# Pydantic model inside model

Tags: python, model, fastapi, pydantic

So i am trying to use an existing pydantic model in another pydantic model, as i've seen on the examples.
Those are my pydantic models:

```py
class DriverCategoryOut(BaseModel):
    internal_id: int
    category: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

```py
class DocListOut(BaseModel):
    driver_categories: DriverCategoryOut

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

This is my route code:

```
@router.get('/document', response_model=shemas.DocListOut)
def get_doc_list(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    driver_categories = db.query(DriverCategory).first()
    return driver_categories
```

I'm getting the error:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for DocListOut
response -> driver_categories

field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

If I change to `response_model=shemas.DriverCategoryOu`t it works just fine. What is wrong with my `DocListOut` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `driver_categories = db.query(DriverCategory).first()` retrieves (and parses a record as a) `DriverCategory`. Assuming that maps perfectly to `DriverCategoryOut`, why would this be automatically parsed to an object that has a *property* that is of type `DriverCategoryOut`?

You might want to try the following:

```
@router.get('/document', response_model=shemas.DocListOut)
def get_doc_list(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    driver_categories = db.query(DriverCategory).first()
    return {'driver_categories': driver_categories}
```

Now, that JSON will be parsed to your `response_model` (in this case, a `DocListOut`).

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to return a string in this case, should there (.. and it would be a bit weird to expect the reference to be resolved inside it in that case)? `return {"driver_categories: driver_category}` should work fine (.. but having the name be a plural seems wrong as well when a single object is returned).

Comment: Whoops didn’t wanted to make it a string, thanks for the catch!

Comment: thanks a lot, that helped!
Guess i should learn about properties to understand why tho :)

Answer (score 0):

there is another way to inheritance your model

```
class DocListOut(DriverCategoryOut):
      class Config:
            orm_mode = True
            # if you want to exclude some fields
            fields = {
                    "internal_id": {'exclude': True},
                  }
```

if your output are lists

```
class DocListOut(BaseModel):
      driver_category: List[DriverCategoryOut] = []
      class Config:
            orm_mode=True
```